# Dictionary<string,string> vs Hashtable<string,string>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

What is exact different between `Hashtable<string,string>` and `Dictionary<string,string>`?

Which is one is better to use in Asp.net MVC?

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition @Darin's answer, the answer depends on your requirements. What are you trying to use it for? Because there are more alternatives:

- Do you want duplicate keys to be allowed? Then there is [`Lookup<string,string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class.
- Do you need case-insensitive key comparison? Then you can use [`NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx).

But usually you avoid using `Hashtable` altogether since `Dictionary<string,object>` is a better replacement.

Answer (score 8):

There's no such class as `Hashtable<X, Y>` in the BCL. There's the [`Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) class which is a non-generic version of the [`Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class. It was used back in the time of .NET 1.0 and 1.1 when generics weren't yet introduced in .NET.

Or maybe you was referring to the [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) class? It represents an unordered collection containing unique elements. It has the standard collection operations Add, Remove, Contains, but since it uses a hash-based implementation, these operation are O(1). It is not key/value hashtable.

> Which is one is better to use in Asp.net MVC?

That will obviously depend on your specific requirements and on what you trying to achieve. So the right question for you to ask is not `Which of X or Y is better in ASP.NET MVC` but `Which of X or Y is better in order to achieve Z in ASP.NET MVC`.